# What is the best way to implement categories and sub categories similar to Kijiji?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there is `acts_as_taggable_on` which is great, but if I want sub-categories like on Kijiji.

I'm wondering what is the best way to do this? Is there a gem for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem [ActsAsTree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) extends ActiveRecord to add support for organizing items into parent–children relationships, which will allow you to create categories and sub-categories.

It's compatible with Rails 3.00 and forward.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good experience with the gem [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) for tree relationships such as categories, especially if you want the ability to drill down multiple layers of subcategories, i.e. subcategories of subcategories.

It comes with many convenient methods which you'll likely use when dealing with records that have tree-like relationships, such as `root`, `descendants`, and `subtree`, (all of which you call on a record), and then whole scopes, such as`roots`.